# What's the easiest way to convert these dataframe String fields to Integers and back again?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using the Spark ALS algo to produce recommendations and it requires the user and product fields to be integers.  I'm bringing in the data as a CSV with strings in those fields.  What's the easiest way to convert those to integers and then back again after I produce output for each user from the algorithm.  The output is in the format:

[Rating(user=16, product=7, rating=0.9847078722254077), Rating(user=16, product=19, rating=0.9756248870987353)]

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that my input data String fields have alphanumeric characters, such as this example row (fields are userid, product, rating (which is already an integer)):
74RTU, Product X, 15

Comment: BTW, I also need suggestions on how to transform it back to a CSV from the structure above (a list for each user, embedded with Rating objects?) - should I append the results for each user into some structure, and then how do I transform that to a CSV in this format: UserID, Product, Rating)

Comment: I suggest you "clarify" your question by editing it and showing exactly what kind of data you have (simplified sample data that demonstrates the problem), what you want done with the digit-letter combinations in the input, and what problem it is causing with what attempted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know what form the data is in, let's assume you can do the conversion one number at a time, say k is your number as a string.

```
>>> k = '15'
>>> type (k)
<type 'str'>
>>> j = int(k)
>>> type (j)
<type 'int'>
>>> z = str(j)
>>> type(z)
<type 'str'>
>>> (k,j,z)
('15', 15, '15')
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that I have alphanumeric characters - see above

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to let pandas read the csv file; it will automatically convert numeric fields into numbers. It's hard to beat since you don't have to do anything (unless you want to overwrite the default types for some columns).

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("products.csv")
```

You can also reverse the process by using `df.to_csv()` to write out your data.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that I have alphanumeric characters - see above

Comment: I suggest you "clarify" your question by editing it and showing exactly what kind of data you have, what you want done with digit-letter combinations in the input, and what problem it is causing with what attempted solution.

Comment: Sample data that demonstrates the problem would be the best explanation.